# Performance of single-constructor disjoint union in fsharp

Tags: performance, f#, discriminated-union

I try to wrap up a primitive type in a single-constructor disjoint union with members:

```ml
type T = | T of int 
  with 
    member inline this.add k = 
      let (T i) = this
      T (i+k)

    member inline this.ret = 
      let (T i) = this
      i
```

I do this to get type safety (not all primitive values are meaningful to me), and because in some settings it is nice to get to pretend the value is an object (e.g., you get to override `ToString()`).

I was expecting the compiler to remove the overhead of the unnecessary tag `T`, but it doesn't seem to be doing that. I try the following two functions, one using the members, one deconstructing and working on the int value 'by hand'. When I disassmble (using fasmi), I get the assembly on the right:

```ml
 let byMembers (c : Card) =
   let d = c.add 0xcafebabe           L0000: push rbx
   let e = d.add 0xcafebab0           L0001: mov ebx, [rdi+8]
   e.ret                              L0004: mov rdi, 0x1147adb08
                                      L000e: call 0x00000001047b6c10
                                      L0013: add ebx, 0xcafebabe
                                      L0019: mov [rax+8], ebx
                                      L001c: mov ebx, [rax+8]
                                      L001f: mov rdi, 0x1147adb08
                                      L0029: call 0x00000001047b6c10
                                      L002e: lea edi, [rbx-0x35014550]
                                      L0034: mov [rax+8], edi
                                      L0037: mov eax, [rax+8]
                                      L003a: pop rbx
                                      L003b: ret

 let byHand (Card i) =
   let d = i + 0xcafebabe             L0000: mov eax, [rdi+8]
   let e = d + 0xcafebab0             L0003: add eax, 0x95fd756e
   e                                  L0008: ret
```

When I benchmark these, I get unsurprisingly that `byHand` runs at roughly .66 the time of `byMembers`, which is undesirable for my actual application.

Am I doing it wrong with the `type T`? Is there a way to type-safely abstract a primitive type in f# such that the compiled output would have no overhead compare to the 'raw' implementation?

Comment: Bonus question: I'm struggling to understand the assembly output. What are the two `call 0x00000001047b6c10` doing? Where did the `0xcafebab0` go?

Comment: This is a discriminated union, so why would the compiler remove code that discriminates? You have chosen a pattern that is popular but bad, because it is not a disciminated union but something much simpler: a record type or class is a simpler way to do the same thing. You are using a discriminated union, with a conflated case and type name (a horror), and expecting the compiler to automatically convert that into a struct class with one value, when instead you could have written the class directly.

Comment: If you add the Struct attribute to a single case DU it should be pretty much erased: `type [<Struct>] T = T of int`.

Comment: @CharlesRoddie this is not at all an unreasonable expectation. See [`newtype` of Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype).

Comment: It's not an unreasonable expectation of `newtype` of Haskell but this question did not ask about newtype or Haskell. It would be an unreasonable expectation of a Haskell algebraic datatype and is similarly an unreasonable expectation of an F# discriminated union.

Comment: @CharlesRoddie I think that was the whole point of the question: what could be another way of encoding such type that wouldn't have a performance implication. And it's not an unreasonable expectation that F# would have such a way.

Comment: I agree that that how to do implement something newtype-like (without restricting to single-case disjoint unions) is the question behind the question, and I did answer that with "a struct class with one value". I.e. `[<Struct>] type T(value:int) = member _.Value = value`. There will be no extra memory used if you do that (no tag because this isn't a DU). There may be a performance implication depending on how the IL gets transformed before it is run.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox excellent, thanks. I've typed up a comprehensive answer for posterity. If you write a short one, I'll accept that?

Answer (score 1):

Add `[<Struct>]`:

```ml
[<Struct>] // <--- here
type T = | T of int 
  with 
    member inline this.add k = 
      let (T i) = this
      T (i+k)

    member inline this.ret = 
      let (T i) = this
      i
```

Disassembling, we find `byMembers` has been optimized down to essentials:

```ml
let byMembers (c : T) =
   let d = c.add 0xcafebabe           L0000: add edi, 0xcafebabe
   let e = d.add 0xcafebab0           L0006: lea eax, [rdi-0x35014550]
   e.ret                              L000c: ret
```

NB! The `[<Struct>]` attribute causes `T` to be stack-allocated and get pass-by-value semantics; presumably this is why the optimizer can remove the unnecessary tag.

The `[<Struct>]` attribute also applies to records and classes, with the same meaning, and yield the desired performance characteristics also in that setting. In this case, there is neater syntax available via the `struct` keyword.

Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/structs).